# Sleep function doesn't work

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using Xcode and I have just started using the `sleep()` function but for some reason Xcode keeps saying `Use of undeclared identifier 'sleep'`.

Is there anyway around this? (As you can tell I'm quite new to C++)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may be because you haven't introduced the `unistd.h` header file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How are headers introduced?